# Set Duration for tooltip in highchart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want to restrict tool-tip in high-charts to display only one second, is it possible ?

There is enable and disable property but that doesn't help me as i need to set duration of time to display tool-tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the default `hideDelay` value:

```
tooltip: {
    hideDelay: 1000
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0hckr9q2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.hideDelay

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply , however the provided solution works in the below case : Mouse out of a series wait for a second it disappears . However what i need is the total duration of time display of tool tip should be one second only even i am on mouse hover state

Comment: Hi @user3361706, Please test this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pw5sjcog/

Comment: Works for me:) Thank you for that